# EF Core Migrations after changing project to use DI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I had a solution with no Dependency Injection. Poor form. However, I have changed the entire app, and it's not fully dependency injection enabled. All was good, until I had to do my first entity framework migration.

In powershell, I cd to my data project, and do the usual:

`dotnet ef migrations add mymigration`

It builds, and then hits me with:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'

In my root application startup, I prepare my DI for my context here:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
   options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Database:ConnectionString")
                    ));
```

The application works fine. It's just migrations, I cannot create.

My context class is pretty standard:

```
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
```

Nothing interesting. Along with the usual modelbuilder works.

Have I done something wrong? Or do I need to change how I do the migrations?

My migrations folder in my data project has many migrations from the pre-DI days.
Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this documentation here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation

You might need a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to have a context for your command line migrations. At least this is how I solved this issue.
I'm creating migrations at the development time with the Factory and then apply them as soon as my application starts against my databases (integration, uat, production).

In my example I'm using a MSSQL local db, which ships with Visual Studio on windows.

```cs
public class DatabaseDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>
  {
    public DataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
      var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");

      return new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
  }
```

Comment: That looks like what I need to do, but battling to see how to implement. I can change my context class to use ```IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<DataContext>```, but in your example, you have the UseSqlServer etc in the context. Mine is in my Startup.

Comment: And I lose my ```protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)``` as it has no suitable method to override now.

Comment: Hey Craig , you can place this class in a subfolder of your project and if I remember correctly - it's pulled automatically when running the migrate command. So you don't need to change your startup code, or do any registration for it.

Comment: Oh! So this is like a dummy class used by the 'migrations' only? The existing code is untouched?

Comment: from the docs:

If a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived DbContext or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the DbContext and use the design-time factory instead.

Comment: Thank you. The examples have the UseSqlServer in this new class. Could I just inject my Config, to point to the right database?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This class is more or less static. So no injection is done here (as far as I know). But you can run the mirgration commands in your startup or from the command line to create sql scripts. I prefer the runtime applying: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime
For SQL Scripts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#idempotent-sql-scripts

Comment: But I guess there are multiple ways to generate your migration (sql or just core at runtime) and how to apply those :)